# Converting .py to .exe getting error no module named userlist

Tags: python, py2exe

I had created a .py file using below

```
from appd.request import AppDynamicsClient
import requests
import datetime as db
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import json
```

i had used py2exe for converting it into .exe , i had created a setup.py file in which included all the required packages command used

```
python setup.py py2exe --include package name
```

it is running fine and creating two folder named dist and build, In dist exe file is present when running the file it is giving the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "appd\__init__.pyc", line 10, in <module>
File "appd\model\__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
File "six.pyc", line 92, in __get__
File "six.pyc", line 160, in _resolve
File "six.pyc", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named UserList
```

I am not using any module as userlist

Comment: You may want to search for the `UserList` module and post the code of where exactly this problem is happening. It could be something about the import path, and could be others. Without specific codes about it, I think it's hard to say anything meaningful.

Comment: i had not used any package as userlist

Comment: It's not in your code, but it is there. Likely at appd\model\__init__. You may want to check there.

Comment: thank Musen 1 in appd\model\_init_  there is from six.moves import Userlist  is present and it is inside python27/Lib/site-packages/appd so i need install six package also

Comment: I tried to do pip install six but it is showing that it is already installed

Comment: I think you want to make sure the version of python you are using has the package six.

Comment: if it was not present then while using it should had given error but it is telling that this package is already installed

Answer (score 0):

I had imported UserList in the file and it was working fine 
Actually, problem is that User list package is inside the six package so it is dynamically loaded on the time generation of .exe so it was not able to load the package that's why it was throwing the error.